# What is the font used in the logo of The Little Market?

Tags: font-identification, script-typeface

I am looking for the font used in Lauren Conrad and Hannah Skvarla’s [company logo](http://www.thelittlemarket.com/):

[image: Handwritten script reading "the little market"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be [Stars_From_Our_Eyes](http://www.kimberlygeswein.com/2011/05/26/new-font-stars-from-our-eyes/) free font:

[image]